# Components appearing on top of my Sidebar in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to create a Login application with a landing page using React Router and Redux. I want the landing page to have a Sidebar that is always present in the following components that are inside the application, for this I have assigned the Sidebar component to a route that is always present on the url. I have done something like this:

**index.js**

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
          <App/>
      </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**App.jsx**

```
export default function App() {
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route path="/p" component={Sidebar} />
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/p" component={Dashboard} />
        </Fragment>
    );
}
```

**Sidebar.jsx**

```
function Sidebar({ logout }) {
    return (
        <div className="sidebar">
            <Button onClick={logout}>Logout</Button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Sidebar.css**

```
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    /* Fixed Sidebar (stay in place on scroll and position relative to viewport) */
    height: 100%;
    width: 75px;
    /* Set the width of the sidebar */
    z-index: 1;
    /* Stay on top of everything */
    top: 3.4em;
    /* Stay at the top */
    background-color: #222;
    /* Black */
    overflow-x: hidden;
    /* Disable horizontal scroll */
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

**Dashboard**

```
export default function Dashboard() {
    return (
        <Fragment>
            Hola
        </Fragment>
    )
}
```

I use Sidebar.css to make the Sidebar to stick to the left of the screen, this is working properly, the problem is the Dashboard component, this is showing on the top of the screen like this:
[image]

How can I solve this and make all the components that I will add to the app to adjust it size for the navbar to appear always on the left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top property affects the vertical position from the top edge.

here you are adding 3.4em hence theres a gap, set it as 0 if you dont want top spacing

```
.sidebar {
    ...other stuff
    top: 0;
}
```

Since this is fixed, it will be on top of other ui,
So for Dashboard you need to set margin-left: 75px (or whatever's the width of the sidebar)

```
    export default function Dashboard() {
        return (
            <div style={{marginLeft: 75}}>
                Hola
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

@Avinash's answer should help you fix your css styling issue.

In addition, I think using layouts and children prop is a better way to go about what you are trying to achieve i.e making `Sidebar` appear in every component.

You can achieve that by creating a `Layout` component and importing `Sidebar` into it. And then every component that will have that sidebar should simply make use of that layout.

`Layout.js`

```
import Sidebar from './Sidebar'

export default function Layout(props) {
    const { children } = props
    return (
        <div>
            <Sidebar />
            {children}
        </div>
    )
}
```

And then your `Dashboard.js` should look like this:

```
import Layout from './Layout'

export default function Dashboard() {
    return (
        <Layout>
            <div style={{marginLeft: 75}}>
                Hola
            </div>
        </Layout>
    )
}
```

This way, you wouldn't have a need for this extra route: `<Route path="/p" component={Sidebar} />`

Comment: Is there a way to the children inside the Layout component to alway have the 75px of margin to the left?

Comment: It's a good approach, the problem is whenever I render a new component that has the Sidebar, the component Sidebar will render again, and for example if I have to do calls to an API inside the Sidebar component, this will do the calls every time I call a component with the Sidebar and can affect to the performance of the app i think.

Comment: Your first comment, yes, so rather than wrap `Dashboard` with a `div` with marginLeft, you can wrap the `children prop` in `Layout` with that marginLeft div instead. That way, any component that uses the `Layout` will always have that marginLeft.